# Drop shadow is above the text

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm adding a drop shadow to a Xamarin.UWP project (but the question is not really Xamarin-specific but UWP in general):

```cs
bool IsShadowSupported => ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract", 3); // SDK >= 14393

if (IsShadowSupported) {
  var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(Control).Compositor;
  dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
  if (Control is Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock textBlock)
    dropShadow.Mask = textBlock.GetAlphaMask();
  shadowVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
  shadowVisual.Shadow = dropShadow;
  ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(Control, shadowVisual);
  ...
  dropShadow.Offset = new Vector3((float)Shadow.GetDistanceX(Element), (float)Shadow.GetDistanceY(Element), -5f);
}
```

It runs and the shadow appears—but above the text, not beneath it. At first I thought this would be determined by the Z coordinate of the offset, but no negative, positive or zero value there changes anything. The shadow looks like this:

[image]

Which is not a bad effect on its own but it's not what was requested: white text and a dark grey shadow beneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `SetElementChildVisual` sets the visual as the last child of the given element, which will make the shadow appear above the `TextBlock`. Unfortunately not even the parent of the `TextBlock` is enough, you should instead have a adjacent element that will host the shadow:

```
<Grid x:Name="ShadowHost" />
<TextBlock x:Name="Hello" Text="Hello" />
```

Now use `ShadowHost` instead of `Control` in your code except for the `GetAlphaMask` call where you should use the `TextBlock` instead.

Of course this is quite some work to make shadows work, which is why you can try to use the Windows Community Toolkit's `DropShadowPanel` instead - see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/dropshadowpanel) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the panel. No, it isn't a solution for me, I'm in a Xamarin Forms platform effect here that makes it necessary to provide a standalone solution. I'll try according to your suggestion.

Comment: You could create a custom Label control which has a custom renderer on UWP which uses DropShadowPanel and TextBlock controls, that might work well

Comment: Yes. But considering that my code does the very same operations as `DropShadowPanel` does, after all, I can just as well insert that extra Grid and be done with it.

Comment: As in a platform effect I don't have access to the control's parent (it's always null), there is no other way out but a custom renderer, yes. In my particular case I could get away with a simpler workaround (swapping the text and shadow colors and negating the shadow offsets) but this is not a universal solution.

Comment: hi @Gábor, Sorry for my understanding, I get it now.