# Offset values for Windows Composition Visual not getting correctly initialized

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-composition-api

I am using UWP and working with the Composition API to programmatically slide items around on the screen and I have found that when the application first starts that the initial slide for many of the elements are not performing correctly. Upon further inspection I have found that the ElementVisual's Offset properties that I use for computing and setting both the initial and destination positions of the animation are sometimes coming up with all zero values for the X,Y,Z values on the very first animation.  Best I can tell all animations of that element from that point forward are working correctly as long as the app keeps running.

The app I am working on is more complex and interesting, but I have created a simplified test application to demonstrate the problem I am encountering.

From a new blank UWP project I add the following GridView and Button to the root grid of the page:

```
        <GridView x:Name="TestGridView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <GridViewItem >
            <Border Width="125" Height="125">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content String 1" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Border Width="125" Height="125">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content String 2" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Border Width="125" Height="125">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content String 3"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </GridViewItem>
    </GridView>
    <Button Height="125" Width="125" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

In the codebehind file I add the following additional using statements, a variable declaration and this event handler:

```
using System.Numerics;  
using Windows.UI.Composition;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting;
using System.Diagnostics;

 Compositor compositor;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var element in TestGridView.ItemsPanelRoot.Children)
        {
            var slideVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(element);

            Debug.WriteLine("Element Offset: " + slideVisual.Offset);

            var slideAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
            slideAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0f, slideVisual.Offset);
            slideAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, new Vector3(slideVisual.Offset.X, slideVisual.Offset.Y + 20f, 0f));
            slideAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800);

            slideVisual.StartAnimation(nameof(slideVisual.Offset), slideAnimation);
        }
    }
```

I also initialize the compositor in the MainPage() constructor:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;
    }
```

I then run the project in Debug mode from Visual Studio.
Pressing the button produces the following output in my Immediate Window (separator lines added in editing for clarity)

```
Element Offset: <0, 0, 0>
Element Offset: <0, 0, 0>
Element Offset: <0, 0, 0>

Element Offset: <0, 20, 0>
Element Offset: <129, 0, 0>
Element Offset: <258, 0, 0>

Element Offset: <0, 40, 0>
Element Offset: <129, 20, 0>
Element Offset: <258, 20, 0>

Element Offset: <0, 60, 0>
Element Offset: <129, 40, 0>
Element Offset: <258, 40, 0>
```

Note that the first of the three elements does animate on the first slide, but the other two do not and that their Offset values are all zero values.

On each slide there after all three elements animate from their previous position as they should, although the side effects from the first slide animation linger on.

I have tried unsuccessfully to find a way to force the elements in our application to update their Offset values so that the initial slide animation for each element works correctly including doing things like inserting a dummy WarmUp animation just before the actual intended animation that very quickly tells the element to either move from its current position to the same position, or a very slightly modified start position to its actual current position.

```
            var warmUpAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();                
            warmUpAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, new Vector3(slideVisual.Offset.X + 1, slideVisual.Offset.Y, slideVisual.Offset.Z));
            warmUpAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, slideVisual.Offset);
            warmUpAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
```

I am guessing this is a bug in the Windows Composition API but I am hoping someone can suggest a simple and effective work around that will force the ElementVisual to correctly initialize after load.

Comment: This case  may be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580042/drop-shadow-is-above-the-text).

Comment: @CoCaIceDew, ho so?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1 - Generally, DON'T use `Offset` to animate the position of Visual's that are created from a `FrameworkElement`. Use the manual `Translation` property instead.

This can be done by calling the following on each element, preferably in their `Loaded` events

```
ElementCompositionPreview.SetIsTranslationEnabled(myFrameworkElement, true);
```

You would then change the animation to something like

```
var warmUpAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
warmUpAnimation.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(0.0f, "Vector3(this.Target.Translation.X + 100f, this.Target.Translation.Y, 0f)");
warmUpAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, new Vector3(0f));
warmUpAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);

slideVisual.StartAnimation("Translation", warmUpAnimation);
```

This used to be **very** evident in the old Composition animation documentation, but they seem to have largely wiped away its mentions from the recent updates. In general the composition documentation isn't very good at all. I literally can't even find the page right now that explains **why** you should use Translation over Offset (which is to do with XAML properties overwriting Composition Properties).

Essentially `Offset` is the absolute X.Y. position of an element relative to its parent set by the XAML rendering engine, and `Translation` is akin to a `RenderTransform` on top of that - the different is XAML will overwrite Composition's `Offset` with its values with no care as to what you put in at the Composition level, but it has no "knowledge" of the `Translation` property so it never overwrites it. `Translation` always applies as an additive to the current Offset. It also **only** works for Visuals created from FrameworkElements - it's unneeded for any other type of CompositionVisual as their offsets don't get changed by XAML.

2 - It may help to call `ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual()` on each target element you know you're going to animate at some point in their loaded events - note it has to be directly on the element that is going to be animated. This ensures the handoff visual is created and fully ready by the time you need it. (Created is asynchronous due to the nature of how Composition APIs works with the system compositor).

Comment: AddExpressionKeyFrame does not seem to be a valid method and the string does not come up with any useful web search results. Any chance you could double check your code example for the suggested Translation approach? As you point out, the documentation on these apis leaves something to be desired.  Thanks.

Comment: @HoloSheep you are correct! Apologies, I use my own extensions that following a builder / "fluent" API pattern that usually lets me chain them together - `AddExpressionKeyFrame` is one of them. It should be `InsertExpressionKeyFrame` - edited the above

Answer (score 0):

I keep running into this same problem when using the Composition api whenever I use it in UWP applications. For whatever reason initial calls to GetElementVisual for UIElements often do not provide correct return results.

I have resorted to running a test in a loop before using visuals for the first time.

As a simple example, if you add the following function to the above sample:

```
    private bool IsCompositionVisualReady(UIElement element)
    {
        var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(element);
        if (visual.Size.X == 0 && visual.Size.Y == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And then insert the following while loop at the beginning of the foreach segment in the Button_Click routine and add "async" to the click handler:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var element in TestGridView.ItemsPanelRoot.Children)
        {
            while (!IsCompositionVisualReady(element))
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
            }

            var slideVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(element);
```

The visuals animate more or less as they should. However, there does still seem to be a slight delay on the last two elements on the first pass of animations.

Comment: For this you can avoid all of this by calling ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(...) in the Loaded event for each visual, or at least once any point in the same timeslice as the method that calls the animation. You don't have to store the visual either, but calling it beforehand ensures the visual is created - and such a thing is asynchronous by the nature of composition working through DWM which exists outside your application.

Comment: @JonnyWestlake Thank you, the subtle detail of making a "warm-up" call to retrieve each visual to force its creation beforehand seems to be the trick I was looking for and was sort of what I was thinking might work (but didn't) in my post above where I tried a warmUpAnimation.

Comment: (For future reference because I can't edit my comment above, it should read `"...or at least once at any point NOT in the same timeslice as the method that calls the animation..."`)